# Simulation of command line input

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I am trying to embed dcraw code into my application. dcraw is a raw image processing command line program in c. To minimize changes to dcraw I figured I would simulate the command line inputs to the main function of dcraw and rename the main function. Code is below:

```
int main() {
int errorReturn;
const char *argArray[5];
argArray[0] = "dcraw";
argArray[1] = "-v";
argArray[2] = "-w";
argArray[3] = "-T";
argArray[4] = "/path/to/file";
errorReturn = dcraw_main (5, (const char **)argArray);
printf("errorReturn = %d\n", errorReturn);
return errorReturn;
}
```

where the dcraw main function is now:

```
int dcraw_main (int argc, const char **argv);
```

The problem is, if there is and odd number of arguments (5 in the example shown), I get:

```
Terminated due to signal: ABORT TRAP (6)
errorReturn = 0
```

If there's an even number of arguments, I don't get that error.

I'm running the above code in CodeRunner. When I embed the code in my application, main() is renamed because there's already a main() function in the application. However it exhibits similar behavior and hangs the program.

Is there a problem with simulating input to a command line program in this way?
TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument array is null-terminated, and the characters of the strings must **not** be `const` - C programs are allowed to modify the arguments passed into `main`.

Use for example this (notice that you then need to *`free`* each of these arguments as they're copied into mutable strings by `strdup`):

```
#define arg(a) strdup(a)

char *argArray[] = {
    arg("dcdraw"), 
    arg("-v"), 
    arg("-w"),
    arg("-T"), 
    arg("/path/to/file"), 
    NULL
};
int argc = sizeof argArray / sizeof *argArray - 1;
```

or this (C99 compound literal, does not leak memory, but block scoped!):

```
#define arg(a) (char[]){a}

char *argArray[] = {
    arg("dcdraw"), 
    arg("-v"), 
    arg("-w"),
    arg("-T"), 
    arg("/path/to/file"), 
    NULL
};
int argc = sizeof argArray / sizeof *argArray - 1;
```

The C99 compound initializer has a block lifetime, so it will be unavailable after the current `{ ... }` block ends.

---

In your case, since it worked for some number of arguments it would hint that the lack of NULL terminator was the reason, but in general case, this is what you'd want to do.

Comment: May be worth a line or two identifying the *compound-literal* within the macro. Probably bewildering for the new C programmer.

Comment: Thanks, that works, and it's easier to use and modify than my original code.

Comment: For anyone reading this later, strdup behind the scenes mallocs memory on the heap, so you get memory leaks if you don't free() it. Admittedly they are small leaks in the scheme of things. The second approach: char[] {a} doesn't leak, or you can use the syntax I head in the question and explicitly add a NULL as the last element of the array.

Comment: @JimMerkel the strdup does not exist to only add null - it exists because the command line arguments need to be modifiable.